$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{n(1+z^2)} $

Determine domain of convergence $\Omega$ for
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{n(1+z^2)}$$
decide whether the sum
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{n(1+z^2)} $$
is an holomorphic function in the region $\Omega$.


I notice that
$$\begin{align*}
|e^{n(1+z^2)}| &= |e^{n(1+x^2-y^2+2ixy)}| \\
&= |e^{n(1+x^2-y^2)}||e^{2nixy}|\\
&\leq e^{n(1+x^2-y^2)}
\end{align*}$$
So I'm interested in the region
$$\Omega = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: x^2-y^2<-1\}$$
$\hskip2in$
Now I have to verify that the convergence is uniform in every compact set, here's the part where I struggle a bit. I choose closed disk as compact set so I think that every point $z \in \Omega$ could be surrounded by a closed disk of appropriate $\varepsilon >0$ radius where the function $g(x) = 1+x^2-y^2$ has a minimum since it's continuous. From this reasoning I think I can find a uniform bound and the convergence is uniform.

Is it a possible solution? Thank you very much for the help!

You need $g(x,y) \le -\delta$ for some $\delta>0$. So you need the maximum of the negative function $g$ on the compact set, not the minimum.

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{n(1+z^2)} =\frac{1}{e^{-(z^2+1)}-1}$$

@geetha290krm I was having some doubts about taking max or min, glad that fifty fifty I choose wrong :’). By the way I’ll deduce that changing min with max and it’s a valid solution right?

Yes, you almost got the entire proof correct except for the confusion between max and min.

@JJacquelin I did not notice that but how that help answering my question, evaluating series's sum garante me uniform convergence?

Of course a comment isn't an answer. This was for information only.

@JJacquelin I hope I did not sound rude, I was just wondering if I was missing something obvious!
